# 3.5mm to RCA/composite video cable not working?

Tags: hardware, boot, setup, composite-video

I just got an RPi 2, a 5V power supply, a microSD card (EMTEC 64GB) loaded with NOOBS, and a cheap keyboard, so I assumed I was good to go for playing with my RPi. I pulled out a 3.5mm to RCA/composite video cable, plugged it into my TV and my RPi, then plugged in my power supply. The red and green LEDs stayed solid, but nothing appeared on the screen (I flipped thru the different inputs to make sure).

Is there something I'm doing wrong? Do I need to buy something else?

Thanks for all your guys' help!

Comment: Google for RPi2 composite and see if anything helps.

Comment: Have you made sure that 3.5 mm Composite is your default output?